# No me corre ninguna animación jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Tengo un `<div id>` llamado *anip*, este lo invoco en el `<script>` e intento animarlo, pero no funciona la animación. Como he dicho, puede ser cualquier animación, solo deseo que funcione.

En el `<head>` he añadido el enlace vinculante a jQuery. Dentro del `<body>` tengo un `<div>` *contenedor* sin estilo, y dentro de este contenedor dos `<div>`, `<header>` y *corpo* respectivamente. Dentro del `<div>` *corpo* tengo el `<div id="anip">`, el cual quiero animar de alguna manera. Estoy aprendiendo a animar en jQuery. Este es el planteamiento.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.slim.min.js"></script>

 <title>Práctica 12</title>
 <style type="text/css">
  #header{
   padding: 10px;
   background-color: #2b82f7;
  }
  h1{
   padding: 10px;
  }
    #anip{
            padding:5px;
            background-color:"blue";
    }
 </style>
</head>
<body>
 <div id="contenedor">
  <div id="header"><h1>Título</h1></div>
  <div id="corpo">
   
   <div id="anip">
        Esto quiero que se anime
      </div>
     
  <script type="text/javascript">
   $('#anip').animate(
     {
        top : "+=50px",
        opacity : 0.25
     },
        300,
   );
  </script>
       
  </div>
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Agradecería mucho la ayuda. Soy nuevo en esta comunidad.

Comment: Hola y bienvenido a Stack Overflow. Si alguna de las respuestas solucionaron tu inquietud, te sugiero aceptarla con el check que hay bajo los votos. Te invito a hacer [el recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para que conozcas la manera como funciona la comunidad.

Comment: Gracias, entendido, estoy explorando y leyendo.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Mmmmm me parece que esa versión de **JQuery** no tiene el método `animate` probé con otra versión y tu código funciona bien, o en todo caso no utilices la versión delgada (*slim*) ya que por lo general, no tiene ajax, no hay efectos y se eliminan los métodos obsoletos.

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <!--<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.slim.min.js"></script>-->
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    
        <title>Práctica 12</title>
        <style type="text/css">
            #header{
                padding: 10px;
                background-color: #2b82f7;
            }
            h1{
                padding: 10px;
            }
        #anip{
                padding:5px;
                background-color:"blue";
        }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="contenedor">
            <div id="header"><h1>Título</h1></div>
            <div id="corpo">
    
                <div id="anip">
            Esto quiero que se anime
          </div>
    
            <script type="text/javascript">
                $('#anip').animate({top : "+=50px", opacity : 0.25}, 300);
            </script>
    
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Espero te funcione. Saludos ;)

Comment: Muchas gracias, me has aclarado el por qué no funcionaba mi código, entonces sería la versión de jQuery que estaba usando, tiene sentido. Gracias amigo, me ha funcionado.

Answer (score 3):

Básicamente lo que cambie fue la instrucción primera del estilo del div. 
Así cuando se anime este se movera de acuerdo a lo que se indique.

También modifique la versión de Jquery, que incluye el método `animate`.

```js
$('#anip').animate(
   {
      top : "+=150px",
      opacity : 0.25
   },
      "slow",
);
```

```html
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <style type="text/css">
        #header{
            padding: 10px;
            background-color: #2b82f7;
        }
        h1{
            padding: 10px;
        }
    #anip{
            padding:5px;
            background-color:"blue";
            position: absolute;
            top: 0;
            right: 0;
            width: 150px;
            height: 50px;
    }
    
    </style>


    <div id="contenedor">
        <div id="header"><h1>Título</h1></div>
        <div id="corpo">

            <div id="anip">
        Esto quiero que se anime
      </div>

        </div>
    </div>
```

Espero te sirva.

Comment: Realmente gracias, me ha servido, funciona, noto que la versión de jquery que estaba utilizando puede ser la razón de por qué el código no funcionaba.