# Problema con JQuery: $(...).fadeIn is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery

Estoy queriendo agregar un efecto al formulario para mostrar un mensaje, pero no me lo toma ya que me salta que el efecto de jq no es una función.

Acá es donde lo estoy queriendo agregar:

```
$('#form').on('submit', function(e) {
e.preventDefault();

console.log(e);

console.log(datos);

// Validar el Formulario...

const { nombre, email, mensaje } = datos;

if(nombre === '' || email === '' || mensaje === '' ) {
    console.log('Al menos un campo esta vacio');
    $('#form').append('<p class="form__error">Todos los campos son obligatorios</p>');
    $('.form__error').fadeIn();
    return; // Detiene la ejecución de esta función
}

console.log('Todo bien...')

$('#form').append('<p class="form__correcto">Mensaje enviado correctamente</p>');
    $('.form__correcto').fadeIn();
});
```

Así tengo linkeados los archivos JS y JQ:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-Piv4xVNRyMGpqkS2by6br4gNJ7DXjqk09RmUpJ8jgGtD7zP9yug3goQfGII0yAns" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="js/data.js"></script>
<script src="js/main.js"></script>
```

Comment: ¿Dónde tienes los scripts?

Comment: Justo antes de que cierre la etiqueta </body>

Comment: Ese error la respondí [aquí](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/317319/146637). ;)

Comment: Genial, muchas gracias :D

Comment: Cuando cambié #form a  $("body").append(...) , funcionó bastante bien para mi.

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [No me corre ninguna animación jQuery](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/317316/no-me-corre-ninguna-animaci%c3%b3n-jquery)